# python dynamic nested dictionary to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

The obtained output below are from query results.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('651f3e6e5723b7c1'), 'fruits': {'pineapple': '2', 'grape': '0', 'apple': 'unknown'},'day': 'Tues', 'month': 'July', 'address': 'long', 'buyer': 'B1001', 'seller': 'S1301', 'date': {'date': 210324}}

{'_id': ObjectId('651f3e6e5723b7c1'), 'fruits': {'lemon': '2', 'grape': '0', 'apple': 'unknown', 'strawberry': '1'},'day': 'Mon', 'month': 'January', 'address': 'longer', 'buyer': 'B1001', 'seller': 'S1301', 'date': {'date': 210324}}



#worked but not with fruits and dynamic header

date = json.dumps(q['date'])  #convert it to string  
date = re.split("(:|\}| )", date)[4] #and split to get value
    
for q in db.fruits.aggregate(query):

               print('"' + q['day'] + '","' + q['month'] + '","' + date + '","' + q['time'] + '","' + q['buyer'] + '","' + q['seller'] + '"')

 
               #below close to what I want but having issue with nested and repeated rows

               ffile = open("fruits.csv", "w")
               w = csv.DictWriter(ffile, q.keys())
               w.writeheader()
               w.writerow(q)
```

I want to create a csv from it.

I am able to get everything exactly like the below table shown but not the fruits. I am stuck at nested dictionary field, and with the dynamic table header.

Mongoexport doesn’t work for me at the moment.

[image: table]

The field fruits could have more different nested key and value for each time.
I am currently still trying/exploring on csv.writer and try to add condition if i found nested dict. [will update answer if i manage to create the csv]
A **hint** to create this csv will be nice to have.
Thank you if anyone is sharing the link to similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem!

We'll need to flatten the deep structure so we can all possible keys from there to form a CSV with. That requires a recursive function (`flatten_dict` here) to take an input dict and turn it into an output dict that contains no more dicts; here, the keys are tuples, e.g. `('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`.

We run that function over all input rows, gathering up the keys we've encountered along the way to the `known_keys` set.

That set is sorted (since we assume that the original dicts don't really have an intrinsic order either) and the dots joined to re-form the CSV header row.

Then, the flattened rows are simply iterated over and written (taking care to write an empty string for non-existent values).

The output is e.g.

```
_id,address,buyer,date.date,day,fruits.apple,fruits.grape,fruits.lemon,fruits.pineapple,fruits.strawberry,month,seller
651f3e6e5723b7c1,long,B1001,210324,Tues,unknown,0,,2,,July,S1301
651f3e6e5723b7c2,longer,B1001,210324,Mon,unknown,0,2,,1,January,S1301
```

```
import csv
import sys

rows = [
    {
        "_id": "651f3e6e5723b7c1",
        "fruits": {"pineapple": "2", "grape": "0", "apple": "unknown"},
        "day": "Tues",
        "month": "July",
        "address": "long",
        "buyer": "B1001",
        "seller": "S1301",
        "date": {"date": 210324},
    },
    {
        "_id": "651f3e6e5723b7c2",
        "fruits": {
            "lemon": "2",
            "grape": "0",
            "apple": "unknown",
            "strawberry": "1",
        },
        "day": "Mon",
        "month": "January",
        "address": "longer",
        "buyer": "B1001",
        "seller": "S1301",
        "date": {"date": 210324},
    },
]


def flatten_dict(d: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Flatten hierarchical dicts into a dict of path tuples -> deep values.
    """
    out = {}

    def _flatten_into(into, pairs, prefix=()):
        for key, value in pairs:
            p_key = prefix + (key,)
            if isinstance(value, list):
                _flatten_into(into, enumerate(list), p_key)
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                _flatten_into(into, value.items(), p_key)
            else:
                out[p_key] = value

    _flatten_into(out, d.items())
    return out


known_keys = set()
flat_rows = []
for row in rows:
    flat_row = flatten_dict(row)
    known_keys |= set(flat_row.keys())
    flat_rows.append(flat_row)

ordered_keys = sorted(known_keys)
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow([".".join(map(str, key)) for key in ordered_keys])
for flat_row in flat_rows:
    writer.writerow([str(flat_row.get(key, "")) for key in ordered_keys])
```